# Change order of second column respect to first column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a mtrix `A` such as

```
A =  data_dir.frame(cbind(x1 = c(0, 2, 0, 5, 9, 1), x2 = c(10, 100, 30, 14, 20, 80)))
> A
   x1  x2
1  0  10
2  2 100
3  0  30
4  5  14
5  9  20
6  1  80
```

My desirable result is:

```
A =  data.frame(cbind(x1 = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 9), x2 = c(10, 30, 80, 100, 14, 20)))
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `order`:

```
A[order(A$x1),]
#   x1  x2
# 1  0  10
# 3  0  30
# 6  1  80
# 2  2 100
# 4  5  14
# 5  9  20
```